# To change publish version format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I need quick help from U all expert guys. Company will have new SAP system soon and it has limitation of maximum 6 character version number allowable. So  need to change publish version style of my C# program from e.g 2.1.2.7 to 2.1.3. I tried a lot to change in publish property, AssemblyInfo.cs but c#(visual studio ) doesn't allow me to do that. What will be the solution?

http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/254/pulisherr1.png
http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/3673/publisherr2.png

My publish version number will be applied to released application files also as shown below picture. I am releasing whole package include folder and setup.exe and application file to our network server from under one folder tagged with latest release number(e.g. Downloader_2_1_2_7). Our SAP system will pick this release number from network.

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/7069/publisherr3.png
http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8421/publisherr4.png

Comment: The solution is to replace the retarded "SAP system".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

At this point my final suggestions are to:

1. Write a service (or a scheduled task) to rename the files in question.
2. See if you can add a "Post-Publish" MSBuild task and rename the files then (though I'm not sure if publish is part of MSBuild.exe).
3. [Contact Microsoft directly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc136615)

As a disclamer, I'm not sure what the ramifications are of re-naming the files, but it doesn't look like a 3 digit version is natively supported at this point.

Hope you find an answer that works!

**EDIT**

From what I can tell, the publish version you are trying to modify is for ClickOnce publishing. The version number has to do with the version of the Package that's generated, not with the application version itself.

From what I can tell through viewing the XML of the csproj file, this version number must include the major, minor, build, & revision numbers.

[image]

The only resulting artifact of the publish version that I could find is in the file system of the publish location.

[image]

As you can see, my file folders are incremented by 1, but I wasn't able to find any reference to 1.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.3 in any of the other files (property windows, etc.)

If your application files are versioned correctly from Assembly.cs, how does this publish version number interfere with your SAP system?

**ORIGINAL**

This compiles just fine:

*Assembly.cs*
[image]

*Properties Window*

[image]

Not sure how your SAP is integrating with these assemblies, but it should be noted that .Net only uses the AssemblyVersion for referencing. The AssemblyFileVersion is for display only. Source: [How to use Assembly Version and Assembly File Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556041)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked. Whenever I tried to omit one letter say revision or minor build, visual studio doesn't allow me to proceed further with an error .."This string is not valid version" and stuck me to do nothing, even I can't minimize C# screen!

Comment: @Ketul: What version of visual studio are you using? Is Visual Studio throwing this error? Is "This string is not valid version" the **exact** error it's throwing? Is the error thrown at compile time? Any other details you could provide would be great!

Comment: I am using visual studion 2005. I am opening C# project in visual studio. The error it is showing is exact word I posted. error throwing during publish time. code is getting compile with assemblyversion and AssemblyFileVersion changed to 2.1.3 but after compiling trying to publish exe file i am getting this error. Where can I sent U pictures of exact error and publish screen?

Comment: Publishing the exe to the Debug/Release folder is throwing the error or some custom publish method is throwing the error? Plenty of free image hosting sites out there (http://imageshack.us/ ,  http://www.flickr.com/ , other ) upload to one of these sites and edit your question to include the images.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I put 2 images on imageshack.us and here are 2 link to view these publish screens and error. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/publisherr2.png/ and http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/pulisherr1.png/. I am trying to publish to release folder with standard method.